# Cassandra default column limit of 100

Tags: cassandra, limit

I have successfully inserted some columns into cassandra, using Java. But when I try to list all the column in cassandra client, it says, that number of columns is limited, and the limit is 100. I need much more than that. Maybe someone knows, how to change this limit?

This is what I get from cassandra's client:

```
[default@Keyspace1] list user;        
Using default limit of 100
Using default column limit of 100
-------------------
RowKey: 313030
=> (column=45454531, value=56616c756531, timestamp=1357880630549)
=> (column=4545453130, value=56616c75653130, timestamp=1357880630580)
=> (column=454545313030, value=56616c7565313030, timestamp=1357880630682)
=> (column=45454531303030, value=56616c756531303030, timestamp=1357880631306)
=> (column=454545313031, value=56616c7565313031, timestamp=1357880630682)
=> (column=454545313032, value=56616c7565313032, timestamp=1357880630683)
=> (column=454545313033, value=56616c7565313033, timestamp=1357880630684)
=> (column=454545313034, value=56616c7565313034, timestamp=1357880630684)
=> (column=454545313035, value=56616c7565313035, timestamp=1357880630685)
=> (column=454545313036, value=56616c7565313036, timestamp=1357880630686)
=> (column=454545313037, value=56616c7565313037, timestamp=1357880630686)
=> (column=454545313038, value=56616c7565313038, timestamp=1357880630687)
=> (column=454545313039, value=56616c7565313039, timestamp=1357880630688)
=> (column=4545453131, value=56616c75653131, timestamp=1357880630581)
=> (column=454545313130, value=56616c7565313130, timestamp=1357880630689)
=> (column=454545313131, value=56616c7565313131, timestamp=1357880630689)
=> (column=454545313132, value=56616c7565313132, timestamp=1357880630690)
=> (column=454545313133, value=56616c7565313133, timestamp=1357880630691)
=> (column=454545313134, value=56616c7565313134, timestamp=1357880630691)
=> (column=454545313135, value=56616c7565313135, timestamp=1357880630692)
=> (column=454545313136, value=56616c7565313136, timestamp=1357880630693)
=> (column=454545313137, value=56616c7565313137, timestamp=1357880630694)
=> (column=454545313138, value=56616c7565313138, timestamp=1357880630694)
=> (column=454545313139, value=56616c7565313139, timestamp=1357880630695)
=> (column=4545453132, value=56616c75653132, timestamp=1357880630583)
=> (column=454545313230, value=56616c7565313230, timestamp=1357880630696)
=> (column=454545313231, value=56616c7565313231, timestamp=1357880630697)
=> (column=454545313232, value=56616c7565313232, timestamp=1357880630698)
=> (column=454545313233, value=56616c7565313233, timestamp=1357880630698)
=> (column=454545313234, value=56616c7565313234, timestamp=1357880630699)
=> (column=454545313235, value=56616c7565313235, timestamp=1357880630701)
=> (column=454545313236, value=56616c7565313236, timestamp=1357880630702)
=> (column=454545313237, value=56616c7565313237, timestamp=1357880630703)
=> (column=454545313238, value=56616c7565313238, timestamp=1357880630705)
=> (column=454545313239, value=56616c7565313239, timestamp=1357880630706)
=> (column=4545453133, value=56616c75653133, timestamp=1357880630584)
=> (column=454545313330, value=56616c7565313330, timestamp=1357880630707)
=> (column=454545313331, value=56616c7565313331, timestamp=1357880630708)
=> (column=454545313332, value=56616c7565313332, timestamp=1357880630709)
=> (column=454545313333, value=56616c7565313333, timestamp=1357880630711)
=> (column=454545313334, value=56616c7565313334, timestamp=1357880630712)
=> (column=454545313335, value=56616c7565313335, timestamp=1357880630713)
=> (column=454545313336, value=56616c7565313336, timestamp=1357880630714)
=> (column=454545313337, value=56616c7565313337, timestamp=1357880630715)
=> (column=454545313338, value=56616c7565313338, timestamp=1357880630716)
=> (column=454545313339, value=56616c7565313339, timestamp=1357880630717)
=> (column=4545453134, value=56616c75653134, timestamp=1357880630586)
=> (column=454545313430, value=56616c7565313430, timestamp=1357880630718)
=> (column=454545313431, value=56616c7565313431, timestamp=1357880630719)
=> (column=454545313432, value=56616c7565313432, timestamp=1357880630720)
=> (column=454545313433, value=56616c7565313433, timestamp=1357880630721)
=> (column=454545313434, value=56616c7565313434, timestamp=1357880630722)
=> (column=454545313435, value=56616c7565313435, timestamp=1357880630722)
=> (column=454545313436, value=56616c7565313436, timestamp=1357880630723)
=> (column=454545313437, value=56616c7565313437, timestamp=1357880630724)
=> (column=454545313438, value=56616c7565313438, timestamp=1357880630725)
=> (column=454545313439, value=56616c7565313439, timestamp=1357880630725)
=> (column=4545453135, value=56616c75653135, timestamp=1357880630587)
=> (column=454545313530, value=56616c7565313530, timestamp=1357880630726)
=> (column=454545313531, value=56616c7565313531, timestamp=1357880630727)
=> (column=454545313532, value=56616c7565313532, timestamp=1357880630728)
=> (column=454545313533, value=56616c7565313533, timestamp=1357880630729)
=> (column=454545313534, value=56616c7565313534, timestamp=1357880630730)
=> (column=454545313535, value=56616c7565313535, timestamp=1357880630731)
=> (column=454545313536, value=56616c7565313536, timestamp=1357880630731)
=> (column=454545313537, value=56616c7565313537, timestamp=1357880630732)
=> (column=454545313538, value=56616c7565313538, timestamp=1357880630733)
=> (column=454545313539, value=56616c7565313539, timestamp=1357880630734)
=> (column=4545453136, value=56616c75653136, timestamp=1357880630588)
=> (column=454545313630, value=56616c7565313630, timestamp=1357880630735)
=> (column=454545313631, value=56616c7565313631, timestamp=1357880630736)
=> (column=454545313632, value=56616c7565313632, timestamp=1357880630736)
=> (column=454545313633, value=56616c7565313633, timestamp=1357880630737)
=> (column=454545313634, value=56616c7565313634, timestamp=1357880630738)
=> (column=454545313635, value=56616c7565313635, timestamp=1357880630739)
=> (column=454545313636, value=56616c7565313636, timestamp=1357880630740)
=> (column=454545313637, value=56616c7565313637, timestamp=1357880630740)
=> (column=454545313638, value=56616c7565313638, timestamp=1357880630741)
=> (column=454545313639, value=56616c7565313639, timestamp=1357880630742)
=> (column=4545453137, value=56616c75653137, timestamp=1357880630590)
=> (column=454545313730, value=56616c7565313730, timestamp=1357880630743)
=> (column=454545313731, value=56616c7565313731, timestamp=1357880630744)
=> (column=454545313732, value=56616c7565313732, timestamp=1357880630744)
=> (column=454545313733, value=56616c7565313733, timestamp=1357880630745)
=> (column=454545313734, value=56616c7565313734, timestamp=1357880630746)
=> (column=454545313735, value=56616c7565313735, timestamp=1357880630747)
=> (column=454545313736, value=56616c7565313736, timestamp=1357880630748)
=> (column=454545313737, value=56616c7565313737, timestamp=1357880630748)
=> (column=454545313738, value=56616c7565313738, timestamp=1357880630749)
=> (column=454545313739, value=56616c7565313739, timestamp=1357880630750)
=> (column=4545453138, value=56616c75653138, timestamp=1357880630591)
=> (column=454545313830, value=56616c7565313830, timestamp=1357880630751)
=> (column=454545313831, value=56616c7565313831, timestamp=1357880630752)
=> (column=454545313832, value=56616c7565313832, timestamp=1357880630752)
=> (column=454545313833, value=56616c7565313833, timestamp=1357880630753)
=> (column=454545313834, value=56616c7565313834, timestamp=1357880630754)
=> (column=454545313835, value=56616c7565313835, timestamp=1357880630755)
=> (column=454545313836, value=56616c7565313836, timestamp=1357880630756)
=> (column=454545313837, value=56616c7565313837, timestamp=1357880630757)
=> (column=454545313838, value=56616c7565313838, timestamp=1357880630758)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The format of list command is

```
  list <ColumnFamilyName> limit X columns Y;
```

where

- limit: Number of rows to return. Default is 100.
- columns: Number of columns to return per row. Default is 100.

So just give:

```
 list user limit 150 columns 200;
```